# Name different files from another file having different names respectively

Tags: python, file, naming

I have created a script to download multiple images. I have another file ***(linkVars.py)*** in which there are URLs of the images to download. This script import the **linkVars.py** file then reads one URL at a time, downloads that image from the URL, and writes it into a file named ***{file_name}.jpg***

Below is the code for the explanation of upper lines:

```
import linksVars as lV # file with urls

def download_url(url):
    # Creating a function 
        print(f"\nDownloading from: ", url)
        file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("=") + 1 # naming image by using text in url
        name_from_url = url[file_name_start_pos:]
        file_name = name_from_url
    
        r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
        if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
       # Opening the image file to write data in it
                    with open(f'{file_name}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                        for data in r:
                            f.write(data)
```

Now, I have multiple names written in **name_file.txt(external file).** As I download the image, I want to name **file_name** in ***{file_name}.jpg*** from one name in **name_file.txt.** Then as the code starts to download the next file, the next name in **name_file.txt** should be assigned to ***{file_name}.jpg*** If someone could help me then I will be grateful!

Below is the complete code:

```
import requests
import linksVars as lV

def download_url(url):
    print(f"\nDownloading from: ", url)
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("=") + 1
    name_from_url = url[file_name_start_pos:]
    file_name = name_from_url

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
                with open(f'{file_name}.jpg', 'wb') as f:
                    for data in r:
                        f.write(data)

links = lV.List1
try:
    for listLinks in links:
        download_url(listLinks)
except(KeyboardInterrupt):
    print("\n\n===> Script ended by USER! <===")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: please share an example of your file, and explain better what is your problem

Answer (score 0):

> Try this:

```
import requests
import linksVars as lV # Importing file with URLs stored in variables
import nameVars as nV # Importing file with names stored in variables

links = lV.List1    # List1 is the list of URLs stored in variables
names = nV.Name1    # Name1 is the list of names stored in variables

# This function will download image from URL and name it from Name1
def download_url(url, names):
    print(f"\nDownloading from: ", url)
    file_name_start_pos = url.rfind("v=") + 1   # It will find "v=" in given URL and move to next line
    name_from_url = url[file_name_start_pos:]   
    file_name = names

    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    if r.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
        with open(f'{file_name}.jpg', 'wb') as f:   # Downloaded file will opened and named
            for data in r:
                f.write(data)

try:
    for listLinks, listNames in zip (links, names): # "For loop" will use two arguments
        download_url(listLinks, listNames)

except(KeyboardInterrupt):
    print("\n\n===> Script ended by USER! <===")
```